# Persist state params when calling $state.go

Tags: angular-ui-router

There's a route param that represents the current site language, defined in the abstract `app` state.

```
angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]).config(["$stateProvider",
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/:lng',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      })
      .state('main.index', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<span>Index</span>'
      })
      .state('main.gallery', {
        url: '/gallery',
        template: '<span>Gallery</span>',

      })
  }
]);
```

For now, everytime calling `$state.go`, I have to add the `lng` property to the route param list, like

`$state.go('main.index', { lng: 'en' });`

even though the current value of `lng` is `en`

Is there anyway to make the `lng` remain the same like the previous state unless we explicitly change it by passing it to the route param list?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value to the lng param in your state definition:

```
  .state('main', {
    url: '/:lng',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    params: {
      lng: 'en'
    }
  })
```

More detail can be found [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to keep the param value of the previous state instead of using the default one.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for misreading.  Why not just make a wrapper service for $state, creating a method that accepts a params object and then calls $state.go with the params you pass, filling in any omitted ones from $stateParams for the state you're leaving?